# Unix File naming conventions

Tags: unix, filenames

I am in process of doing a remote to local copy using `rsync`and the file list is picked up from a txt file which looks like below

> ```
> #FILE_PATH FILENAME
> /a/b/c test1.txt
> /a/x/y test2.txt
> /a/v/w test1.txt
> ```

The FILE_PATH is the same for remote and local servers. The Problem is, I need to copy the files to a Staging area in the local first and then need to move it to the `FILE_PATH`, so as to make sure Integrity.

If I simply copy all the files to the Staging area, `test1.txt` will get overridden. So I thought I can go with clubbing the `FILE_PATH` and `FILENAME`, thus it gets unique. To do so, I can not create the file as `/a/b/c/test1.txt` in my staging area.

So I thought to replace `/` with special chars that support Unix.
Tried with `- _ : .`, I got conflicts with all this.

> -a-b-c-test1.txt

How I can achieve copying files to the same Staging directory though the file names are of same but supposed to reach different directory

your thoughts pls.

Comment: Why not put everything in a (compressed) tar archive, copy that to the remotes and un-tar it there?

Comment: The remote machine is so orthodox that I cannot create tar balls there

Comment: You say "I can not create the file as `/a/b/c/test1.txt` in my staging area."  Why can you not do that?  Is it not allowed?  Or do you mean that you tried to do so but it did not work?

Comment: @dg99 how can we create a file with name `/a/b/c/test1.txt` in a different mount. `touch: cannot touch ‘/a/b/c/test1.txt’: No such file or directory`